# Aura Component now working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, integration

[image]Component:

```
<aura:component controller="COVID19" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

    <aura:attribute type="CCOVID19WRAPPER[]" name="COVIDLIst" />
    <aura:attribute type="List" name="MyColoumns" />
    <aura:attribute type="boolean" name="ShowSpinner" default="false"/>
    <aura:Handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>


        <lightning:datatable data="{!v.COVIDLIst}" coloumns="{!v.MyColoumns}" keyField="id" >

        </lightning:datatable>


     </aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    init : function(comp, event, helper) {

        comp.set('v.MyColoumns',[
            {label:'Country',fieldName:'Country',Sortable:true,type:'text'},
            {label:'New Confirmed',fieldName:'NewConfirmed',Sortable:true,type:'text'},
             {label:'Total Confirmed',fieldName:'TotalConfirmed',Sortable:true,type:'text'},
             {label:'Total Death',fieldName:'TotalDeaths',Sortable:true,type:'text'},
             {label:'New Death',fieldName:'newDeaths',Sortable:true,type:'text'},
             {label:'New Recovered',fieldName:'NewRecovered',Sortable:true,type:'text'},
             {label:'Total Recovered',fieldName:'TotalRecovered',Sortable:true,type:'text'}          

           ]);

        var action=comp.get("c.getCOVID19Method");
        action.setParams({});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response)
        {

            var state=response.getState();
            if(state=="SUCCESS")
           {
               comp.set("v.COVIDLIst",response.getReturnValue());

           }

         });

         $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
})
```

Apex Class:

```
        public class COVID19
          {
            @AuraEnabled
           public static list<CCOVID19WRAPPER> getCOVID19Method()
             {
             list<CCOVID19WRAPPER> listWrap= new list<CCOVID19WRAPPER>();
           String endPont='https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
       http ht= new http();
       HttpRequest httReq= new HttpRequest();
       httReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
       httReq.setMethod('GET');
       httReq.setEndpoint(endPont);
       HttpResponse httRes=ht.send(httReq);
       system.debug('response-->'+httRes.getBody());

       JSONParser jparse=JSON.createParser(httRes.getBody());
       while(jparse.nextToken()!=null)
       {
           if(jparse.getCurrentToken()==JSONtoken.START_ARRAY)
           {
                while(jparse.nextToken()!=null)
                   {
                       if(jparse.getCurrentToken()==JSONtoken.START_OBJECT)
                       {
                               CCOVID19WRAPPER cv=(CCOVID19WRAPPER)jparse.readValueAs(CCOVID19WRAPPER.class);
               if(String.isNotBLANK(cv.Country))
               {
                   listWrap.add(cv);
               }
                       }
                   }
           }
       }
       system.debug('wrapper-->'+listWrap);
       return listWrap;

   }


 public class CCOVID19WRAPPER{
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Country;

     @AuraEnabled
    public string CountrySlug;

     @AuraEnabled
    public Integer NewConfirmed;

     @AuraEnabled
    public Integer TotalConfirmed;

     @AuraEnabled
    public Integer newDeaths;

     @AuraEnabled
    public Integer TotalDeaths;

     @AuraEnabled
    public Integer NewRecovered;

    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer TotalRecovered;

}   


}
```

When I see preview of this component, getting blank screen.Ideally it should display the data from COVID19 API result. Not able to track the missing thing.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a number of typos. Notably, JavaScript and Lightning are cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. This means that `aura:Handler` should be `aura:handler`, `Sortable` should be `sortable`, `newDeaths` should be `NewDeaths`, etc. You need to review your code to find any other characters that are incorrect. Check the documentation if you're not sure. You also have some spelling errors. `coloumns` should be `columns`. This definitely prevents the data from being rendered correctly. Also, the output type needs to be fixed; number fields don't render when you use the `type:'text'` data type.

As an aside, you don't need Apex in modern components. Simply set a CSP Trusted Site, and you can call the service directly. Here's a working example I pulled together from your original post:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <aura:attribute name="data" type="List" default="[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="myColumns" type="List" default="[]" />

    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.data}" columns="{!v.myColumns}" keyField="Id" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.myColumns',[
            {label:'Country',fieldName:'Country',sortable:true,type:'text'},
            {label:'New Confirmed',fieldName:'NewConfirmed',sortable:true,type:'number'},
            {label:'Total Confirmed',fieldName:'TotalConfirmed',sortable:true,type:'number'},
            {label:'Total Death',fieldName:'TotalDeaths',sortable:true,type:'number'},
            {label:'New Death',fieldName:'NewDeaths',sortable:true,type:'number'},
            {label:'New Recovered',fieldName:'NewRecovered',sortable:true,type:'number'},
            {label:'Total Recovered',fieldName:'TotalRecovered',sortable:true,type:'number'}          

        ]);

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(
            'GET', 
            'https://api.covid19api.com/summary'
        );
        xhr.addEventListener(
            'load', 
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                let results = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                results = results.Countries.filter(function(record) {
                    return !!record.Country;
                });
                results = results.map(function(result, index) {
                    result.Id = ''+index;
                    return result;
                });
                component.set("v.data", results)
            })
        );
        xhr.addEventListener(
            'error',
            function() {
                console.log('failed to load resource')
            }
        );
        xhr.send(null);
    }
})
```

*(Note: sorting, etc was not implemented, this is only meant to demonstrate the needed fixes from your current source)*

Comment: Thanks. Got the issue.  Was using coloumns , it should be columns. Also corrected the other typos. Thanks for notifyng :)

Comment: @Thanks sfdcfox.But iam not able to see any data in Table???

Comment: I can see all the data.working for me.

Comment: @Suren Great! Glad I could help out.

Comment: @sfdcfox iam not able to see the data &  i copied code twice. console.log i can see :failed to load resource.. can you please help me on this ..learning from your code

Comment: @AnnappaPH Did you set up a [CSP Trusted Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/csp_trusted_sites.htm#!)?

Comment: no sfdcfox. I havent setted up